# Compare timestamp with working times PHP

Tags: php, date, if-statement, time, compare

```
$timestamp = TIME_NOW;

if ($timestamp <= 8 && $timestamp >= 17)
{
   echo "Please watch our workoing times!";
}
```

The user sends a message via input text to my PHP code
I would like to check if the timestamp the user is sending a message is in our working time.

Anybody got a idea?

Comment: You need to state what have you tried and what is the error. For this specific question DateTime already has plenty of functions to compare if a given time is in some time interval.

Answer (score 0):

then get the corresponding hour and test it (also note the usage of `||` instead of `&&`):

```
$h = date('H', $timestamp);
if($h < 8 || $h >= 17){
     //outside of working hours
}
```

Comment: ahh kind of upset that i still make mistakes like this...
thanks a lot man, gonna try it now :)